# RoR; Third party library wrapper for specific needs with service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any best practice to where third parties wrapper libraries are settled on rails application?

I've been developing with **`app/service`** driven way, so it's easy to encapsulate the action behind the scenes.

*Ref: http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html*

Now the problem is

**Where should I put third party library wrappers for specific needs?**

For example,

- *Mailchimp: wrapper for email subscription*
- *Prawn: The wrapper for PDF receipt*
- *Slack notifier*
  ....

I could create gems for each ones, or put them into models.
If the code is big enough such as PDF receipt wrapper, I could go for creating gem, but if it's small I don't think it's good to put neither model/gem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you.

You can put custom code in new files in `config/initializers` - these will be required automatically.

It's also common to put code in `lib/` and add it to the autoload path (there are other questions for this).

You could make a model for each service as well. You don't necessarily need a database table for models (there are other questions for configuring this).

I think this information (where to put custom code) is really integral to rails and I see a lot of beginners confused by it.